# the key to all the doors of knowledge

Tags: meaning, definite-article, indefinite-article, quantifiers

a. He has a key to all doors of knowledge.

b. He has a key to every door of knowledge.

c. He has a key to each door of knowledge.

d. He has a key to all the doors of knowledge.

============

a1. He has the key to all doors of knowledge.

b1. He has the key to every door of knowledge.

c1. He has the key to each door of knowledge.

d1. He has the key to all the doors of knowledge.

Which could be used if one key opens all the doors?

The idea of 'a door or knowledge' is obviously a metaphor.

======================

I don't suppose a single key could open all the doors of knowledge, but let's assume that is possible. I just want to see how the grammar works.

Many thanks.

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? If the wording of the prepositional phrase would determine whether he has one key or multiple keys?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. Precisely. My guess is that some of them could be used in both cases and some only in one. (one key for all doors or one key per door)

Comment: I don't think *any* of your versions unambiguously asserts the he has either one key for all doors or one key per door. In the latter case you can unambiguously use plural ***keys***, and for the former I might introduce the term ***skeleton** key*. But it's fairly pointless asking people to vote on whether the singular or plural would be understood in the context of a usage where imho it makes absolutely no difference to the *actual* meaning. He has or can access a wide range of knowledge; it's irrelevant whether he has one or multiple different "keys" to do this.

Comment: You could sidestep the distinction by speaking instead of the (or a) [**master key**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_keying) to such doors.

Comment: door of knowledge is not great.

Answer (score 3):

They are all a bit rubbish because the metaphor is flawed.

A door *leads to* something. We'd normally say "*the door **to** [x]*", not a door 'of' something. It would then sound a bit clumsy to say "*a key **to** the door **to** knowledge*".

Also, why does knowledge have many doors? Instead of saying "all doors", why not just say "*all knowledge*"?

Further, if all knowledge is being spoken of collectively, how many keys are there to the same thing? Why "*a*" key?

I would say:

> He has *the* key to all knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sentences:

> He has a|the key to every room in the hotel.
>
> He has a|the key to each room in the hotel.
>
> He has a|the key to all rooms in the hotel.
>
> He has a|the key to all the rooms in the hotel.
>
> He has *keys* to every room in the hotel.

The form of the prepositional phrase does not *entail* anything about the number of keys he has, no matter which determiner we use with "key", *the* or *a*. He could have a master skeleton key or individual keys. It is only the plural version, **keys**, that indicates unambiguously that he has more than one key, and the prepositional phrase entails nothing in that respect. But exactly how many is not known: there could be three storeys in the hotel with 10 rooms each, and he may have only 3 keys if each floor has a separate master key. All that is entailed is that there is more than one key.

That said, in *practical everyday contexts*, listeners are likely to *infer* that he has individual keys, one per room, when **each** and **every** are used in the prepositional phrase, especially if **the** is the determiner for **key**, and likely to infer that he has a single master key when **all**  or **all the** appears in the prepositional phrase, again especially if **the** is the determiner for **keys**.